# Why both absolute change and relative change populated with no output for function build in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wrote function in pandas  to calculate absolute change and relative change of amount basis on place, year. However I am getting no output for both absolute change and relative change. Below is the code

```
#Importing the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Building function
def calculate_change(df):
    df['absolute_change'] = df.groupby(['place', 'year'])['amount'].diff()
    df['relative_change'] = df.groupby(['place', 'year'])['amount'].pct_change()
    return df
#Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'place': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014],
                    'amount': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
calculate_change(df)
```

Looking for an output as below:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this code doesn't produce any output because there are no calls to functions which produce output: no `print`, no `sys.write`. This code shouldn't produce any output, so this is correct behavior.

Comment: Did you want to add `print(df)` *after* the call to `calculate_change` to see the result?

Comment: (There's no particular need for `calculate_change` to return `df`, since the argument is being modified in-place, and indeed the standard Python convention is for mutating functions to return `None` instead of the object.)